# String types not allowed (at 'layout_height' with value 'match-parent')

Tags: android

I am using the scroll View in my activity page.In the starting of the xml I am using this scrollView in whichI have different LinearLayouts.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView    
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match-parent"    
    android:layout_width="match-parent">


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.hsports.bandpop.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">    

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:text="POP BANDS"
        android:gravity="center"    
        android:textSize="50dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"    
        android:paddingTop="100dp" >

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="50dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SIGN IN"
            android:onClick="checkSignIn"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="REGISTER"
            android:onClick="registerForm"
            android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The error I am getting is:
Error:(7, 28) String types not allowed (at 'layout_height' with value 'match-parent').
Error:(9, 27) String types not allowed (at 'layout_width' with value 'match-parent').

Comment: clean your project and rebuild

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's `match_parent` not `match-parent`.
Notice the `_` and not`-`. Change that in your `ScrollView`'s `layout_height` and `layout_width`